# AttributeError: object has no attribute

Tags: python, xml, odoo-8

In my custom Odoo module, i have to call a python function on a button click. I followed the exact way as in the documentations. But i got error as follows..
`AttributeError: 'book.meeting' object has no attribute 'checkout_function'`

My code is as follows..

```
class BookMRoom(models.Model):
 _name="book.meeting"



 name=fields.Char(string="Enter booking person name",required=True)
 company_name=fields.Many2one('res.company','Enter your company name',required=True)
 start_time=fields.Datetime(string="Starting date",select=True,required=True)
 end_time=fields.Datetime(string="Ending date",select=True)
 meeting_room=fields.Many2one('mroom', 'select the room',required=True)
 room_info=fields.Many2one(comodel_name='mroom', field='description')
 amenities=fields.Many2one('mroom','Select amenities')
 ob =fields.Many2one('mroom')

 @api.multi
 def checkout_function(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
    #raise Exception('Coming Inside Checkout Function')
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    self.end_time=current_time
    meeting_obj=self.env['mroom']
    meeting_room.status='available'
    return meeting_room.status
```

My XML file..

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="book-form">
   <field name="name">book.meeting.form</field>
   <field name="model">book.meeting</field>
   <field name="type">form</field>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
 <form string="booking_view_form">
        <sheet string="Book meeting room">
          <label for="name" string="Booking person name"/>      
          <h1>
             <field name="name" placeholder="Booking person" class="oe_inline" string="Booking person"/>
          </h1>
          <group>
             <group>
                 <field name="company_name" string="Company name"/>

                 <field name="meeting_room" string="select a room" options="{'no_quick_create':True,'no_create_edit':True}"/>
             </group>
             <group>
         <field name="start_time" string="Booked date"/>
         <field name="end_time" string="Ending date" help="Give check out time after the usage of room" disable="True"/>
         <button string="Check Out" name='checkout_function' type="object"/>
             </group>
          </group>
        <notebook>
           <page string="Room description">
               <field name="room_info"/>
           </page>
           <page string="Amenities of the room">
           </page>
        </notebook>
        </sheet>
     </form>
   </field>
 </record>

 <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="booking_action">
     <field name="name">Book meeting room</field>
     <field name="res_model">book.meeting</field>
     <field name="view_type">form</field>
     <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
     <field name="view_id" ref="book-tree"/>
     <field name="help" type="html">
          <p>To book a meeting room click create</p>
 </field>
 </record>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: you checkout_function is a class method, i think you forgot indention

Comment: If indentation is not correct, it will show that type of error. But i never got such error.

Comment: ok, let me explain it more clear, there is no such method checkout_function in class

Comment: Check my class, it contain checkout_function.

Comment: I'd recommend skimming the Python style guide [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Basically, add spaces after commas and between equal signs. Makes code more readable.

Comment: now it does, but it hadn't

Comment: Do you ever create `book.meeting`? I don't see `BookMRoom` referenced in the XML.

Comment: @Hugo Rivera Yes, in my XML file i have specified my model name as book.meeting!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case basically the issue is comes because of you have not upgrade your customized module properly and may be with not to restart the odoo server form the terminal after creating your method.

second point is important for your hear `cr,uid,ids,context=None` using that method arguments not needed to do so in newly API decorator  method in your model (class).

please try to check restart the odoo server and then check the affect within that module action.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: Your answer was helpful. Thanks

Comment: @AKHIL MATHEW Happy to help :) :)